# Instagram fetching tag recent user media after a max_id

Tags: api, instagram

Lets asume I fetch recent user media for a tag... And that I am able of storing in a database the information that it is returned to me by the API.

The media ids are something like [0-9]+_[0-9]+, and lets asume that one day later, I want to fetch only new data, so I order the media, that I stored in my DB, by instagram's created time, then I select the one that its the newest and grab its id something like '121231232213123_12312312312'.

Then I use that Id as the max_id attribute for the API endpoint https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/{tag_name}/media/recent, I would assume, that I would get new user_media or an empty array if no one had upload anything.

The thing is that I receive all the same data, its like if it not filtering my results nor using the max_id.

is this correct behavior or should I do something else?

thanks,

ps: I posted this same issue also on google groups:

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/instagram-api-developers/QyjCORkjr3I

Comment: Max and MIn ID are used to parse through the paginated data response, they aren't parameters for the actual query to the API.

Answer (score 4):

I found 2 tips, that can be useful for you:

1. You should use `min_id`, in order to get new media. `max_id` will return photos, older that the one with this id.
2. It's better to use [live API](http://instagram.com/developer/realtime/) in order to update your DB with new photos dynamically.

**UPDATE:**

Instagram live API is deprecated now. However you can now use webhooks subscription system which is very similar to facebook. Details can be found in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34931909/2568409) answer.

Comment: Is there a way to get all photos from a month?

Comment: You always can iterate through the list of recent media & check the date (compare it with 1.month.ago or smth)

Comment: how can i get the post data ?

Comment: By making request to Instagram API. After you made it you should get JSON with all the post data like this: http://pastebin.com/qmcPgyYM

Comment: this created_time output is such freak for me ... 

"created_time" => "1404817910" - noticed this is a 2014 picture
another created time => "1383952734" - and this a 2013

Comment: NP, you can always use ruby Time.at(....) to get the exact time. For example Time.at(1404817910) gives 2014-07-08 11:11:50 +0000 for me :)

Comment: Did any one figure out how to get images between a particular time range

Comment: The link in your answer is now broken.

Comment: @Ionut The whole answer is Deprecated now actually. Over years API changes unlike stackoverflow answers :P . I'll update the answer with more recent link.