# Instagram Media Subscriptions not working for some users, working for others

Tags: ruby-on-rails, instagram, instagram-api

I am developing an Instagram application (in Ruby on Rails, using the IG Gem) that monitors specified hashtags and gathers posts with those hashtags.  In the last week, something weird has begun to happen: some of our users (including my own test account) are unable to post to certain tags.  If they post a photo with that tag, the system does not get the subscription POST from Instagram.  The same photo can be sent by another user and it shows up just fine.  The 'problem user' (there are several) can then post to another tag, and the photos come through.

To recap, we have SOME users that can not post to SOME tags.  Most users can post to any tag.  I have examined both tags and users, and can find no differences between those that work and those that do not.

Does anyone have any insights on this one?

I've researched this, and can find no info on this particular situation.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it has anything to do with tags.

I subscribe to receive posts from authenticated users (object=user & aspect=media), nothing hashtag related, and have a similar problem.  Some users I get every post, some users I get none of their posts.

Re-authenticating them doesn't help.

I'm working with limited data, but *so far* it seems like I'm only receiving updates from the first 10 or so users that connected.

In [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34931909/345599) [nithinisreddy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3516614/nithinisreddy) mentions that the data is being "sampled".  I think this is the reason.