# Instagram API Subscribe inconsistently working

Tags: instagram-api

I have experienced significant variability when using the Instagram Subscription API.  For the most part, the API will not post updates to my end-point as specified during the subscribe initiation.  My understanding is that the subscription is configured correctly as any of the updates from my personal account are received.

There seem to be reports across the web talking about significant delays.  However, it is my experience that accounts that work do so within seconds but in most instances no subscription messages are never received.

There was discussion on the web also regarding queuing of updates sent through to the subscribe API.  Which may make a little sense, however a queue would suggest that updates would be received eventually.

I have requested **basic** permissions, which is sufficient to request public media from each registered account.  Yet, there I have a gut feeling that these permissions could be the problem, so I have started the process of requesting **public_content**.

At this stage there seems to be a number of developers experiencing similar issues, yet no resolutions.

Has anybody been able to resolve this issue?

Comment: Any luck?  I've resorted to polling...

Answer (score 0):

I'm subscribed to aspect=media object=user and experiencing a similar issue.

For some users, I'm notified 95% of the time.  For other users, I've never been notified of a single post.

In [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34931909/345599) [nithinisreddy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3516614/nithinisreddy) mentions that the data is being "sampled". I think this is the reason.  Hopefully it improves after the tags/locations subscriptions are deprecated.